# Python: What is the `is` function?

Tags: python

This might be a stupid question, but what exactly is the `is` function, and when would one use it?

From the context, i guess i could infer that it's equivalent to `==`; but if that's the case, why have both? The [Built-in Functions Reference](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html) shows nothing, and `help(is)` returns a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: `x is y` if and only if `x` and `y` holds the same object.

Comment: Isn't `x == y` the same thing? Why have both?

Comment: No, because you could have two objects with the same values, but they wouldn't be the *same* objects. Suppose you and I live in the same apartment complex. Our apartments might be absolutely identical in every way (`my_apartment == your_apartment`), but they're two different places (`my_apartment is not your_apartment`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`is` checks if the objects have the same identity. `==` only checks if they are equal.

```
>>> L1 = [1,2,3]
>>> L2 = [1,2,3]
>>> L1 is L2
False
>>> L1 == L2
True
```

Comment: Do you know where the is reference on this? I take it it's not in Built-in Functions.

Comment: In other words, `L1 is L2` <=> `id(L1) == id(L2)`

Comment: Also note that according to PEP 8, you should use `is` when comparing to `None`.

Comment: @NoobSaibot: type `help("is")` in a prompt.

Comment: @Maxime: That's the ambiguity that led me to ask the question in the first place, thanks!